# Gulp - Basic concat/minify doesnt output file

Tags: javascript, gulp

My code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    var styles = [
        'node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css'
    ];

    return
        gulp.src(styles)
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(concat('libs.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
});
```

Environment:

- Source file exists.
- Output directory exists and is writable.
- Output is clean, no errors.

Console output:

```
root@bite-srv:/var/www/test# gulp css
[12:51:27] Using gulpfile /var/www/test/gulpfile.js
[12:51:27] Starting 'css'...`
[12:51:27] Finished 'css' after 582ms
```

This doesn't output any css.

What is wrong?

**== EDIT ==**

Found the problem is here:

```
// This doesn't work
return 
    gulp.src(styles)
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));

// This works
return gulp.src(styles)
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
```

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript performs automatic semicolon insertion. So this:

```
return 
    gulp.src(styles)
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
```

Is transformed into this:

```
return; // <- Execution halts here!

gulp.src(styles)
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(concat('libs.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/assets/css'));
```

For more information, see [Beware Of JavaScript Semicolon Insertion](https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/).